# Block-by-Block, Voxel-by-Voxel: The Ice Sage

Tags: trove

So I'm playing Trove (and dismaying the lack of Touhou fans,) and I drew one-too-many parallels between the Ice Sage and Cirno.

My main issue with the whole matter is that the model is not connected at the start. I am completely unable to see how the parts interlock, thus making it difficult to keep the symmetry of the colours.

So, is there a way to assemble the entire Ice Sage model and repaint it from there? If so, how? And if there isn't, are there any tricks to determining the connection of the pieces?

Comment: You seem to have missed an entire paragraph in this question:

"The main issue is that..." The main issue with what?

Comment: It's not so much an issue with everyone, but for me and me alone. The issue is `that the model is not connected at the start.`

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://chrmoritz.github.io/Troxel/#b=C_P_ice_mage_lvl3_ui)? - Your best bet is to do it by eye... (Since we don't have access to the animations) | That's what I did with the [Dracolyte](http://chrmoritz.github.io/Troxel/#b=c_p_dracolyte_lvl3_ui).